# prime number checking without for loop in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to obtain prime number in verilog. For this I used counter, which counts on the rising edge of every clock. Using the value of counter, I must get prime number. My question is how I can check the count value is prime or not. I can use for loop to check prime, but know that in verilog for loop is not a good way because it takes many clock cycles to finish for loop. I have to check the prime number without for loop. Can anyone help me to check the count is prime without loop.

```
module prime_clk ( input clk, input reset) 
  parameter N =1000;          // size of array

  reg [31:0] prime_number[0:N-1]; // memory array for product       

  integer k=0 ;               // counter variable   
  integer result_done =1;     // controller
  integer count =0;     

  always @(posedge clk )     
  begin     
    count = count+1 ;
    if (count%2 !=0 || count%3 !=0 )
    begin
      prime_number[k] <=  count;
      k               <=  k + 1;       
    end 
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: With `for-loop` you can check if a number is prime in one cycle, but max frequency of that module would be very low. Without `for-loop` you'll definitely need more than 1 (i.e. a lot) cycle.

Comment: ok . i can use for loop. please, can you tell me the efficient way of using for loop

Comment: when i use for loop, the system become very slow.. so for loop method is not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not described how you are planning on checking prime for each number, I am going to assume you are planning on taking the modulo of each number below it to test if it is devisable.

When checking for prime you only have to check it is not devisable by the primes below it, as all other numbers are made up of multiples of the primes.

There are a 168 primes below 1000. There fore to check for the primes in 1 to 1000 you either need 168 parallel modulo operations or you can overlock the design to reuse the same hardware. Having to deliver a prime in the same amount of time you need to design for the worst case or allow the time to change, more and more clock cycles for the bigger numbers.

I think it is worth mentioning at this stage that actually putting the primes in to a ROM or Look up table will be much smaller than the hardware to generate them.

An example using multiple clock cycles to check primes:

```
integer test  ;
integer check ; //Counts 1 to k
localparam S_INC   = 2'b01;
localparam S_CHECK = 2'b10;

reg [1:0] state;

initial begin
  prime_number[0] = 'd2;
  state           = S_CHECK; //Check set count first
  count           = 'd3;
  k               = 'd1; //0 preloaded
  check           = 'd0;
  test            = 'd1;
end

always @(posedge clk ) begin
  if (state == S_INC) begin
    $display("State: Incrementing Number to check %d", count+1);
    count <= count+1 ;
    state <= S_CHECK ;
    check <= 'd0;
    test  <= 'd1; // Safe default
  end
  else if (state == S_CHECK) begin
    if (test == 0) begin
      // Failed Prime test (exact divisor found)
      $display("Reject %3d", count);
      state           <= S_INC ;
    end
    else if (check == k) begin
      //Passed Prime check
      //Use k+1 so that 2 is number 1, 3 is 2nd etc
      $display("Found the %1d th Prime, it is %1d", k+1, count);
      prime_number[k] <=  count;
      k               <=  k + 1;
      state           <= S_INC ;
    end
    else begin
      $display("Check");
      test  <= count % prime_number[check] ;
      check <= check + 1;          
    end
  end
end
```

Working Example on [EDA playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/BzX);

Comment: Thank you sir Morgan for helping me. My plan was that every 50 prime number it should return a 50th prime number and so on.

Comment: @fame313 no problem, questions which show effort should do well. Although after the first 50 primes you are going to have a more and more work todo. Remember there are only 168 primes below 1000. and 1229 under 10,000.

Comment: Yes, i calculated the 50th primes and it get more clock cycle due to more number of  calculation. Now i have one more problem which is how i can calculate the simulation time of calculation of one prime number. It means that no of clock cycle to calculate one prime number.As we also know that a large prime number get more clock cycle than a small prime number for calculation. can you help me?? i am very thank full to you

Comment: @sir Morgan ,,,, . This method in not sufficient way to compute the prime number.  when i have to start the prime number from 17 , it  does not compute correctly. it also give the number in output which are not prime number

Comment: @fame313 This method of calculating primes require knowledge of all primes below it. This is the optimisation to avoid dividing by all numbers less than it.

Comment: but how i can do this..  if i want to start prime number from any random number .for example , if i want to get all prime numbers which are above than 50. ?  i have to store precious prime number ?

Comment: @fame313 Calculating prime numbers efficiently has been work of many doctorates, it is not a simple task. It is beyond the scope of this comments section and should probably belong on a mathematic stack exchange site. BUT the code shown divides by all previous primes to check if it is prime. This was an optimisation, so just remove it and **divide by all numbers below** it, it is a minor change to the loop. If your stuck with the change post a new question on how to change make the loop start with any number.